# update datagridview cell style

Tags: c#, datagridview, styles, refresh

I am trying to allow the user to change the color of the datagrid displayed in my app.

for this I use user settings and colordialog boxes.

problem is, when I try to update the color, it isnt displayed, and I either have to close/reopen the app to see the changes, or load a completly different DGV (they are in a tabcontrol).

here is the code I use at the update:

```
AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Properties.Settings.Default.CellBackColor1;
```

am I missing something?

I tried to refresh the DGV, but it doesnt change a thing.

Comment: Have you tried calling [DataGridView.Invalidate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.invalidate.aspx)?

Comment: yes, that was my first try, but no luck with that either.

Comment: Stab in the dark, and maybe far from the best way to do this, but set dgv.Visible = False: dgv.Visible = True

Comment: not very elegant but does the trick :P thanks for the idea. however Ill still wait to see if something nicer comes up

Comment: I didn't run into any problems using your code you provided. As soon as I set the `BackColor` after a button click, it immediately updated the colors. How are you calling your update code?

Comment: when validating the color form Ive set up. the datagrids are on my main window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a `Button` to a form that opens up a `ColorDialog` and waits for the users to select a color. If the user hits the OK button, it first saves the setting and then sets the dataGridView.CellStyle.BackColor to whatever color the user selects. This forces an immediate update of the form with the correct background color.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (colorDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        Properties.Settings.Default.CellBackColor1 = colorDialog1.Color;
        dataGridView1.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = colorDialog1.Color;
    } 
}
```

I assume your `Form.Load` and `Form.FormClosing` events handle the saving of the settings.